# How to remove spaces between letters and print them on one line?

Tags: python

I am stuck guys...

I have a for loop that works perfectly, but I don't know how to remove spaces. I tried using the `sep=""` in the print function, but that didn't work out. I get this error:

> "sytnax error while detecting tuple"

What I want to achieve is this:

> abcd.... (so glued together, on one
>   line).

I've placed them on one line, like this:

```
for letter in range(96,126): 
    a_y = chr(letter)

    print(a_y),
```

Hence the `,` which I use to print them all on one line. My question: is this approach correct?

And the other one: how on earth can I glue the outputs together? I tried using `append` and `sep=""`, but both just don't work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `print(a_y, end="")`

Comment: Do you perhaps mean `range(96, 126)` - else your for loop will never run there... also - you can do: `from string import ascii_lowercase; print(ascii_lowercase[:25])`

Comment: `import string; print string.letters[26:]`

Comment: @JonClements: whoops, yes. And @ Jmat, it keeps saying: "sytnax error while detecting tuple"

Comment: Are you using Python 2? If so, do you have `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of your script?

Comment: The OP doesn't want to import the `string` module. See the previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40674736/how-to-make-this-for-loop-in-python-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to [Tiger-222's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40676405/1708751), you can combine with map:

```
print ''.join(map(chr, xrange(96, 126)))
```

Result

> `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}

Answer (score 2):

You can use a comprehension list:

```
>>> ''.join([chr(n) for n in range(96, 126)])
'`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}'
```

And the reverse:

```
>>> ''.join([chr(n) for n in reversed(range(96, 126))])
'}|{zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba`'
```

---

Or, if you really want to use the `print` function:

```
from __future__ import print_function

for letter in range(96, 126):
    print(chr(letter), end='')

# Reverse
for letter in reversed(range(96, 126)):
    print(chr(letter), end='')
```

Comment: Is there no way I could do something with the print function? I don't get why sep and end are not working...

Comment: In any cases, list comprehensions are faster than explicit `for` loops. But I edited my answer ;)

Comment: @Siyah It's much more efficient to gather the individual chars into a string (or a list, and then call `''.join()` on the list) than to use `print()` to print the chars one at a time.

Comment: Thanks guys, appreciated... so I can conclude there is no way at all that I can glue them together and so, without using the import function?

Comment: @Siyah You can't use the `print` statement to glue the chars together without spaces. If you _really_ insist on using `print` to glue the chars together then you will have to use the `print()` function.

Comment: What is the difference between the function and the statement?

Comment: @Siyah: Actually, you can make it _look like_ they're glued together by using a backspace (`chr(8)`), eg `for i in range(97,105): print '\b' + chr(i),` but that's gross, since the output will contain pairs of space & backspace chars as well as the letters you actually want to print.

Comment: @Siyah: There's quite a bit of difference between the `print` statement and the [`print()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print). For one thing, you can't supply `sep` or `end` arguments to the `print` statement: it's a statement so it can't take args.

Comment: Thanks mate, appreciated it!

Answer (score 1):

Try any one of the following whichever suits your need.

```
>>> import string
>>> string.ascii_lowercase
>>> 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

>>> string.ascii_uppercase
>>> 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

>>> string.letters
>>> 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
import string
print string.letters[26:]
```

or

```
print ''.join([chr(n) for n in range(97, 123)])
```