# Making a pyramid shape of a sequence gives error

Tags: python

I have a list of letters I am outputting, which works fine. Now, I want to get it into a pyramid shape.

This is the error I am getting:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

I have noticed that I need to multiply the outcomes with a space, like this:

```
def pyramid(latest_letter):
for letter in range(102,latest_letter):
        print(first_part_of_letters(letter) *' ' + second_part_of_letters(letter-2)) * '* '
```

I have seen people using this to make a pyramid shape, so I am not understanding why this isn't working. Should I convert the sequence to a string first? I don't want to change this function that much.

Comment: The error you are getting is because of `first_part_of_letters(letter) *' '` as your trying multiply the `string` with `' '`. Multiplication on strings can be performed only with `int` value

Comment: I think that you have already asked the same question a few hours ago and you deleted it. You had an answer to your problem in that question, so why are you asking again?

Comment: @Jalo: I never delete questions. If I would, my account would be blocked anyway, so you are wrong. If i had an answer, I wouldn't ask it again ;)

Comment: Alright, I don't have proofs, so I won't argue about that issue. However, there was a question about that this morning and it was deleted, don't know why

Comment: No problem Jalo. Thanks @MoinuddinQuadri. So you would suggest to convert it into an int first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I believe that it is in continuation to the question you asked [*How make this for loop work?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40674736/2063361). Here, I am updating the logic in [*my original answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40674848/2063361) in order to generate the pyramid. The idea to get that output to be printed in the form of pyramid is to multiply `' '` based on the position of your alphabet. Hence, it could be written as:

```
import string
alphs = string.ascii_lowercase   # returns string of lower case characters
last_letter = 'f'
index = alphs.index(last_letter) # get index of the `last_letter`

for i in range(index):
    print ' '*(index-i-1), alphs[:i]+alphs[i::-1]
#          ^ print ` ` blank space based on the value of `index - i-1`
```

which print the output as:

```
     a
    aba
   abcba
  abcdcba
 abcdedcba
```

Answer (score 0):

Here some proposal independen of your code examples:

```
letters=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I']

ind =0
width =1 

while ind+width<len(letters):
    print(letters[ind:ind+width])
    ind+=width
    width+=1
print(letters[ind:])
```

This gives the output:

```
['A']
['B', 'C']
['D', 'E', 'F']
['G', 'H', 'I']
```

For future posts:
It helps a lot, when you post a working minimal example of you code. Usually your points gets clearer then as well